# Play Framework Processing partial form

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using the Play Framework and I've got the common use case to update a model with a form in a controller action. But I've some issues understanding the concept behind it because this is just working if you have a form which includes ALL of the properties of the model. If you have a just a partial form, e.g. editing just a password of a user model, this method destroys the model, because it sets the other properties  of the model to null. 
Is there any "official" solution to that problem? Any way Play updates just the existing properties?

```java
public static Result update(Long id) {
    Model model = Model.findById(id);
    Form<Model> filledForm = modelForm.bindFromRequest();
    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(edit.render(filledForm));
    } else {
        model.update();
        flash("message", "Created new Model!");
        return ok(index.render());
    }
}
```

Probably the solution lays somehow in the fact that the bindFormRequest() method can be called with additional parameters, like Strings or a Map of Strings? But I can not find out the purpose of that. Some insight into that would be great as well.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a recent project, I needed this kind of feature and I had to reimplement the Form class (based on the original Play Form) to allow an additional parameter to the `bindFromRequest()` method.

Taking your code as an example, it would become something like this :

```java
Model model = Model.findById(id);
Form<Model> filledForm = CustomForm.form(Model.class).bindFromRequest(model);
```

The idea is to only modify the fields defined in your form and keep the other fields of your model unmodified.

To allow this specific binding, you have to redefine the `bind(Map<String,String> data, String... allowedFields)` method (along with the `bindFromRequest`) with something like this :

```java
public Form<T> bind(T instance, Map<String,String> data, String... allowedFields) {

    DataBinder dataBinder = null;
    Map<String, String> objectData = data;
    if(rootName == null) {
        dataBinder = new DataBinder(instance);
    } else {
        dataBinder = new DataBinder(instance, rootName);
        objectData = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String key: data.keySet()) {
            if(key.startsWith(rootName + ".")) {
                objectData.put(key.substring(rootName.length() + 1), data.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of creating the `DataBinder` with `blankInstance()` as the standard Play Form class does, you create it with you model instance as the constructor argument.

Comment: That's a great generic approach. But where exactly have you implemented it? In your specific project or directly in the Play core? And have you any idea what the purpose of the already existing parameter of the bindFromRequest method are?

Comment: I've created a CustomForm class in my specific project that extends play core Form class. So I just need to use my CustomForm class instead of play core's one when I need this partial binding feature.

The `data` parameter contains the data from the request (have a look at the play core `Form.bindFromRequest()` source, it constructs a data Map and give it to the `bind()` method). The `allowedFields` is an optional parameter used to restrict the binded data (it's a Spring DataBinder feature).

Comment: I guess I get it wrong but isn't restricting the binded data what I want?

Comment: Restricting binded data will only tell Play to don't bind all the data found in the request. Binding will still be applied on a "blank" instance of your model, making all the previously persisted data in the fields of your Model that are not part of the `allowedFields` be lost when you call the `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution. What I would do is make a more service oriented application. 
Where you create forms and models for specific actions : `updateUserPassword`, `updateUserEmail`, etc. and in your model implement those simple methods.

Comment: Ok, that's right, it would be a solution. But then I have to do everything manually: Getting the specific form data with bindFromRequest().data().get("password") and performing a validation because I guess the hasErrors mehtod can not be applied anymore.

Comment: All you have to do is create model that fits your form. If you only update a password, create a UpdateUserPassword model and a UpdateUserPasswordForm. That way, you can keep all your validation but on your model, not on the entity.

Comment: Isn't that a little bit of a overhead? Creating for every case a model would lead to a lot of redundancy because properties can overlap.

Comment: You can make Forms extends each other. Believe me, maintenance will be much easier doing this. BTW, this is the way Play suggest handling forms for the Scala version.

Comment: Do you mean Forms extend each other, or Models extend each other? Any official link to any Play ressource or example suggesting that method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you taking a look at scala direction, as you can merge both scala and java in one project, with scala your form maybe a `tuple` for example:

`val someForm = Form(tuple("user_id" -> number, "password"->text))` and then from your request you can use it to perform your model update:

```
someForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
formWithErrors => {
BadRequest
},

data => {
// update method takes two parameters user_id and password to update
User.updatePassword(data._1,data._2)
Ok("...")
}
)
```